# IOS Shortcuts: Setting (nested) dictionaries

Tags: shortcuts-app

I am trying to set values in a nested dictionary - similar to pythonic `dict["key1"]["key2"]=value1` in Apple's my shortcut app on IOS 13. I fail even with a simple dict see attached screenshot which should add an element to the dict. The endgame is to modify EXIF metadata via the Metapho app - [non-working example attached](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/6b17e3b301bf4cb7a31bb1be6e9d66e8)

I  used ttwo approached

1. use a basic operation to modify dictionary
2. use prexisting shortcuts to modify dicitonaries as outline on the following Reddit threat [Dictionary utilites](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9yxq9s/dictionary_utilities/).

To reproduce you need to download the attached shortcuts - and Dictionary utilties for the examples using those.

I first checked if I can modify a non-nested dict and nonnested dict.

## Modifying non-nested dictionary

Using core tools I cannot add a key-value pair to a dictionary.
[Minmal non-working exampleas per below](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/9ed90912077143bcbbd46714e02129c1).

[image]

[image]

## Modifying non-nested dictionary using Dictionary tools

[Minmal working example](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4598f1589cc344ed933ed7afc117ad9b)

## Modifying nested dictionary using Dictionary tools

Using the same tools to modify nested dicts does not work.
[Minimal non working example](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/08f4e04ff11e49c78a90908e9596e9e2)

Any help greatly appreciated. [Asked same question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863385/ios-shortcuts-setting-nested-dictionaries-with-application-to-modify-exif-dat)

Comment: It looks like your question is referencing an image but that image isn't visible.  I can see you have 2 image url's but only 1 image is visible.

Comment: There is a 100 rep bounty on the stackoverflow version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863385/ios-shortcuts-setting-nested-dictionaries-with-application-to-modify-exif-dat